# How to Hide/Show top panel in layout?

Tags: android

I'm trying to show menu and other icons in the top panel. This has to to overlap on the ImageView in my layout.
I'm not sure how to make this part overlap over ImageView, and how to alter the layout to achieve this.

The pic below is the implementation so far:
[image]

I'm looking to modify as shown in below pic:
[image]

I'm not sure how to add the top-most transparent panel including the menu icon, "My Feed", and the other two buttons to overlap on top of the existing ImageView.

This top panel need to be shown when the app is launched. It hides on click. Again when clicked, it shows up.

Comment: you need to use actionbar for this!

Comment: I don't think that is a action bar. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: thats is actionbar . they use animation effect in hide and show

Comment: you can get u r ans here https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Just use a toolbar from the support library and set the background with a semi transparent black color (i.e #BF000000)

The layout should be something like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <ImageView>
  <Toolbar>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The layout I have currently is:
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView>
        <TextView>
        <TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Is a FrameLayout essential?

Comment: You can keep your relative layout, as long as the toolbar is the last view in the layout

Comment: Thanks, it is working! Now figuring out a way to hide/show the toolbar whenever there is a touchevent on the activity.

Comment: Add "android:clickable=true" to your relative layout xml, and assign a click listener to it, with toolbar.setVisibility(toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the way to do it. Hope it will be useful for any other developer facing a similar issue.

Changed the layout to FrameLayout, and then created a new layout for the toolbar. Then included the new toolbar layout into FrameLayout:

```
 <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```